# Proof of sufficient condition for an extension to be unramified

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, unramified-extension

We are given a complete discrete valuation field $K$ and its finite extension $L$. Denote $k=\mathcal O_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K$ and $l=\mathcal O_L/ \mathfrak{m}_L$. Assume that $k$ is a perfect field. I want to proof the following criterion.

> $K\subset L$ is unramified iff  $L=K(\alpha),$ where $\alpha\in \mathcal O_L,~$ $p\in \mathcal O_K[x]$ is minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ and $\overline{p}\in k[x]$ is separable.

I fully understand the proof for the $\implies$ direction, but I am having some trouble with $\impliedby$ direction.

To be precise, while proving $\impliedby$, if $\overline{p}$ is guaranteed to be irreducible, then the proof becomes clear - we have $k\subset k(\alpha)\subset l$ with first extension being of degree $[L:K]$ and, since $[l:k]\leq [L:K],$ we have $l=k(\alpha),$ so $[l:k]= [L:K]$ which is the definition of unramified extension.

Any ideas how I could prove that $\overline{p}$ is irreducible? I have seen a variant of Hensel's lemma (which ironically does not seem to be equivalent to Hensel's lemma) that guarantees it, however I hoped that there could be an alternative approach without that.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you say more on your objection to using Hensel's lemma?

Comment: Kinda did not want to prove a whole separate lemma and hoped that there was something easier. On the other hand, thinking about it now, we have very little information apart from what's required in the lemma (that is, apart from our polynomial being separable), so it was naive to think that there was a proof easier than that of the lemma's. So, I ended up going through the lemma's proof.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "variant of Hensel's lemma"? What is this variant, and what do you consider to be the original Hensel's lemma?